# natbib (apalike): Changing format of page numbers in citations

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style

I want to add page numbers to my citations, in the format (Author, 2021:50). Is there a way to do this with natbib, apalike style?

I know it's possible to use

```
\citep[p.50]{Author2021}
```

to get (Author, 2021, p.50), but I don't want it in this format.

I have already made a copy of the apalike.bst file for other reasons, so I can edit that if necessary.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, thank you so much!